# Git Commit or Git Stash error

Tags: git, github

On my local host, if I check the `git status`, it says `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.nothing to commit, working directory clean`, however when I go to prod repository and try to do `git pull`, I'm getting the below error:

> Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>       Includes/file1.php
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

May I know the reason behind this error and how to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory is dirty because you have uncommitted work there.  If you want to complete your `git pull` you can either commit your changes via:

```
git add path/to/file1
git add path/to/file2
# ...
git commit -m 'Your commit message'
```

or you can try `git stash`, which will clean out your working directory and stash it way for later use.

There is a third option actually.  If you don't want any of the work you have done since your last commit you can throw everything away via:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

But you should only consider this option if you really don't need this work, otherwise make a commit or stash.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used `git add .` and then `git commit -m` option in my local directory before pushing those changes to my prod. Ideally, it should have committed all my changes. Then why it is saying on my prod server that changes are uncommitted

Comment: What does `git status` show you?  Are there any modified files?

Comment: Nopes, this is what it is showing `On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: This is a different message from your original question.  Can you explain this?

Comment: My local host is my working directory, where I make and test the changes. I did `git add .` and `git commit -m` before pushing the changes to the prod. On my prod, I tried doing `git pull` then the error msg is displayed, as posted in my original poster

Comment: and if I check the git status on my local host/working directory it say `n branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'. nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: There must be tracked files present which are causing this.  Use `git checkout -- path/to/file` on each of these files, then try to pull again.